# forwarding avahi-daemon socket to chroot

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, cups, bind-mount, avahi

I have a raspberry pi 3b+ installed with raspbian stretch and I have installed an i386 chroot.

The problem is the CUPS server require avahi-daemon for printer discovery and I haven't been able to get avahi-daemon to work in the chroot.

My goal now is forward the host's avahi-daemon to the chroot by

```
mount -o bind /run/avahi-daemon path_to_chroot/run/avahi-daemon
```

but according to the CUPS error logs in the chroot,

```
Unable to communicate with avahi-daemon: Daemon not running
```

How can I successfully forward the host avahi-daemon to the chroot?

Comment: Try chmod -R a+Xr /etc/avahi/

Comment: Is that inside the chroot? And also, what is the reason for it?

Comment: Your error message is sometimes caused by avahi permissions problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, avahi-daemon communicates via dbus, so I needed to mount the dbus, not the avahi-daemon.

This:

```
mount -o bind /run/dbus path_to_chroot/run/dbus
```

fixed it.